# Swift navigation controller - Hide view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I have a problem with the navigation controller and the view. However, I have created a view with a constraint: "Top Space to: Top Layout Guide : 0". I get this result with the simulator:

[image: layout in simulator]

How to get the view correctly?

Thank you!

**EDIT** :

The problem is the top of the view is hidden by the navigation controller. On my screenshot, you can see that the segmented control is cut ! The top of the view is not show, even in the storyboard file.

Comment: check the properties under Top Bar in Storyboard for your viewController, maybe can help you

Comment: your screenshot is not showing anything, please describe your problem clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `edgesForExtendedLayout` property to report which edges of your view controller extend underneath navigation bars or other system-provided views.

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = []
```

Answer (score 0):

Select your view controller from **stoaryboard**,then unselect the
**Adjust Scrollview Insets**

[image]